# SSH Connection Lost

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

I have recently started using iptables, and I executed `iptables -F` without knowledge of what it might do. And suddenly I have lost connection to the node. I can't even ping the node. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: This belongs over on serverfault

Comment: This question is off topic for this site. I suggest posting it on the unix/linux site instead or superuser.

Comment: It's offtopic, and, you are sc**wed... You might just as well have yanked the network cable. So, without alternative access (unfirewalled connection or physical), you are going to be stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need physical access to the computer and either restart the firewall script or simply reboot the server (but that's the "rude" way of fixing this).

If this computer is hosted at colocation company you need to either contact their support and ask them to reboot the machine (do not give them your password) or sometimes they have some sort of remote rebooting mechanism. Look through the FAQ of the colocation provider.